# Node.js Recursive Loop fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, jquery-callback

Below is the **Node.js** Script. It downloads the images contained in a div. The loop works fine for **9.86%** that is upto **id = 36.** When id > 36 it exits the loop. I am using the node 0.12 version. The loop **needs to run 365** times before its completion. I am usign the method of **recursive callback**.

**Code:**

```
//Required modules
var fs = require('fs'),
         cheerio = require('cheerio'),
         request = require('request');

//Default Variables
var baseURI =  'http://www.website/';
var year = 2013;
var id = 1;
var savePath = process.argv[2]; 

//Download Function
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
    request({ uri: uri }, function(err, res, body){    
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var imgDiv = $('#img-wallpaper').children()['0'];
    if(err)
        console.err(err);
    if(typeof imgDiv !== 'undefined') {
    request(imgDiv.attribs.src).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);}
    });
};



//Main Function
console.log("Downloading . . .");

// Loop function to create a recursive effect
(function loop(){
    download(baseURI+year+'/'+id+'/wallpaper/', savePath+id+'.jpg', 
    function(){
        console.log(((id/365)*100).toFixed(2)+'% completed');
        if(id == 330) 
            year = "2014";
        if(((id/365)*100) != 100){
            id=id+1;
            loop();}
        });
})(1)
```

Comment: Why are you recursing when there's no dependency between the loops? Why not dispatch all the download calls and gather up the results?

Comment: Image Write will be 'partial'. The callstack buffer gets filled up resulting in socked hang up error!.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that if you set the starting value for the `id` more than 35 (36?) the script is not downloaded any images?

Test the script on the fixed uri and on the fixed image by changing only the variables. Script is expected to work out? If this is the case:

- Or not called callback for `body request`
- Or a false condition `typeof imgDiv !== 'undefined'`
- Or not called callback for `request image`

Thus, when an error in one of these points the script stops working. It is necessary to change the severity of conditions.

Comment: If i change the condition to id <= 365 then if id>36, the script works, but if id = 1, the script stops at 36. I think the second option is causing the error. Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 0):

As @stdob said, The error was caused due to

- Or a false condition typeof imgDiv !== 'undefined'

Though the answer is not the right way to overcome the error, it is more of an hack type. It ignores the error and continues the script!

```
if(typeof imgDiv !== 'undefined') {
    request(imgDiv.attribs.src).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
}
else{
    id++;
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
}
```